# How to fix aspect ratio of allowedit window in cordova camera plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I am using cordova camera plugin for my angularjs app.
Plugin is working correctly.
I want to capture photo witn 300:400 aspect ratio always.
Also I want to allow cropping by specifying allow edit option.

Problem I am facing:
I have set aspect ratio targetWidth and targetHeight to 300:400.
I have set allowEdit to true.

My mobile camera window aspect ratio can vary to any ratio. sometime it can be 1:1, sometime 3:4, etc.

When I capture Image as allowedit set to true I got cropping window.
(Problem is here, I want to fix the aspect ratio of that cropping window).

So though camera window aspect ratio is 1:1. I will get resulting image in 300:400 aspect ratio always (as cropping windows aspect ratio will be fixed)

Please guide me how I can fix the aspect ratio of cropping window (allow edit window) in cordova camera plugin.

Thanks in advance